# Custom actions in WP_List_Table

Tags: wordpress, admin

When using the `WP_List_Table` class to create a table in the admin, is it possible to create a custom action other than `edit` and `delete`?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table.

What version of Wordpress are you using?

If you not only want to display the items but also want to manipulate them you have to define some actions. For example:

```
function column_booktitle($item) {
  $actions = array(
            'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&book=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['ID']),
            'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&book=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
             );
  return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['booktitle'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can create my own sublinks like the ones in the Post post type where it says *All | Published | Trash*?

Comment: Hi @enchance I have just updated my answer to explain how to do this.

Comment: @Brett - Have you an example of the function that handles the edit / delete book actions?